‍ <-- this symbol show yellow empty square box in front in VS Code

original code "   <Table.Th>‍Team ‍‍‍Up Bonus (TUB)</Table.Th>"

point in nothing show, no hints, but code can compile without error.
some kind of intelisence bug or error at visial code?

This can be a zero width character. You can read it here

A useful resource: Unicode Character Inspector

It could be a bug but probably not for the reason you're thinking of. This is VS Code's unicode highlight feature. Specifically, VS Code at the time of this writing think's it's from the category of "invisible characters" (see for yourself. put "editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": false, in your settings.json file). And... sure. There are invisible characters in there. Each "‍" is really this:
U+1FAF1 U+1F3FB U+200D U+1FAF2 U+1F3FD

The second and fifth are Fitzpatrick modifiers, and the third is a zero-width joiner. Those are invisible characters, but I don't think it's intended that VS Code is highlighting as if there are (visible) "invisible" characters. The combination of those code points in that sequence is a visible character. Also notice how VS Code 1.89 is only adding that invisible unicode character highlighting if the sequence of ‍ are immediately followed by an alphanumeric character... Something is weird (and I think wrong) about that. I'd suggest you raise a bug ticket.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
